# mysql column order for varchar and ints

Tags: mysql

Is there a speed difference when accessing tables with:

```
INT,INT,INT,VARCHAR(255),VARCHAR(255),VARCHAR(255),VARCHAR(255),VARCHAR(255)

OR

INT,VARCHAR(255),VARCHAR(255),VARCHAR(255),VARCHAR(255),VARCHAR(255),INT,INT
```

As in, does putting fixed length columns first make things faster?

TO Clarify: First column INT is index in both, auto incrementing.  Its myism, but would innodb make a difference?  I have no known way to test at the scale I expect at this stage unfortunately, hence asking...(7 million rows) Further, assume varchars are each filled with 100 character strings and unoptimised.

Answer (score 1):

If your database is MyISAM you will only obtain and speed edge on queries without index for fixed sized columns if ALL your columns are fixed. I mean, it would obtain quicker responses using:

```
INT,INT,INT,CHAR(255),CHAR(255),CHAR(255),CHAR(255),CHAR(255)
```

No matter what the order, and when I say "without idex" I mean, if you perform a query using your table primary key, it's already unique indexed, so no matter what your table is fixed or not it will take the same time. For texts, to obtain speed increases in text searches it's better idea to use Boolean Full Text Searches: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html. Of course for this to work fast you need FULLTEXT indexes in the text values you're performing a search.

InnoDB will not provide you any better response times, it's used to work with transactions, and other functions not available in MyISAM.

If you still need more speed for text searches I recommend you to move your table to Apache Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers focus on the speed of text search, missing the point of the question. They also presume a few things about the indexing and searching that also miss the point.

So, discard thoughts on text search as it's unrelated.

Now, if you index on an integer field it will be quick, no doubt. But what if you have several integer fields. Only one index will be used (multi-index will not give you what you want). If the search criteria is over multiple fields, the best choice of index will be determined and you'll get the regular speed bump on that. When it has to check the other criteria, though, will it have to scan the columns or will it optimize on knowledge of where, from the index-provided offset, the column it is checking exists? If it has to do this scan on a million rows, one could conceivably greatly reduce the complexity by optimizing on this knowledge, and one hopes this still happens as we have all this effort in providing varied length/fixed-length columns.

The most useful suggestion in the above answers was to try it on a big chunk of data. That's a good idea. I've often wondered exactly this, but I've never bothered to check. To set up the problem, try this:

4 columns, int, int, int, text: random numbers in the ints, random length text in the text. Record the values you used, make 1 million rows. index on the first int, search with where statement on each of the int values. try each search 100 times, try 10 searches.

next step, same setup, except put the text as the second column instead of the fourth. Use the same data as you used in the first test. Check to see if it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Measure with data you expect to have there and see for yourself ;)

Seriously, it should not be a significant difference - you'll get speed boosts several orders of magnitude larger by creating useful indexes on that table.

Comment: ("useful" depends on the queries you'll be running against the table)